# iPHone splitting the UIPIcker question

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do I split the UIPicker into multiple parts, like the date picker only not the Day, month, and year - my own specified variables such as - Gender and age?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your datasource method

```
– numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
```

needs to return 2, or however many parts you want.

Then, in your other delegate and datasource methods, you need to take into account what component it's referencing, and populate/handle accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, that splits the picker - but how do I reference each side individually?